# Strange Insert Into error

Tags: .net, vb.net, insert

```
 Private Sub InsertMisclAddInTranCons()
    'Insert the Debit/Credit tran of Miscl Exp into the Tran Consolidated table under the Sale voucher group header//:
    Dim SQLTranCons As String = "Select * From TranConsolidated"
    Dim DATranCons As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DSTranCons As New DataSet

    Dim TCNewRowDebit As DataRow
    Dim TCNewRowCredit As DataRow

    DATranCons = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLTranCons, Con)
    DATranCons.Fill(DSTranCons, "DSTranConsHere")

    'Dim Row As DataRow
    Dim I As Integer


    ' MsgBox(DSMisclExpDetTemp.Tables(0).Rows.Count)
    For I = 0 To DSMisclExpDetTemp.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        Dim SQLDebitMax As String = "SELECT Max(TranConsolidated.ID) AS MaxOfID FROM TranConsolidated;"
        Dim DADebitMax As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim DSDebitMax As New DataSet
        Dim DebitMax As Double

        DADebitMax = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLDebitMax, Con)
        DADebitMax.Fill(DSDebitMax, "DSDebitMaxHere")
        DebitMax = DSDebitMax.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)

         For Each Row In DSMisclExpDetTemp.Tables(0).Rows
        TCNewRowDebit = DSTranCons.Tables(0).NewRow
        With TCNewRowDebit    'This block will create the debit row//
            .Item(0) = DebitMax + 1
            If txtIfEditingSaved.Text = "" Then
                .Item(1) = txtTranNo.Text   
            Else
                .Item(1) = txtIfEditingSaved.Text  
            End If
            .Item(2) = txtInvNumber.Text
            .Item(3) = dtpSaleInvoice.Value
            .Item(4) = txtComboAccount.Text     'Inserts the Debit account selected in the voucher
            .Item(5) = DSMisclExpDetTemp.Tables(0).Rows(I).Item(2)  'Amount is entered here
            .Item(6) = DSMisclExpDetTemp.Tables(0).Rows(I).Item(4)   'This is the opposite account ID which will be used for the ledger display from TranConsolidated.
            .Item(10) = 2   'This is a sub transaction of sales tran
            .Item(11) = frmAddMisclinSale.txtTranSubType.Text
        End With
        DSTranCons.Tables(0).Rows.Add(TCNewRowDebit)

        'Credit Entry===
        'Get the max ID for credit//:
        Dim SQLCreditMax As String = "SELECT Max(TranConsolidated.ID) AS MaxOfID FROM TranConsolidated;"
        Dim DACreditMax As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim DSCreditMax As New DataSet
        Dim CreditMax As Double

        DACreditMax = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLCreditMax, Con)
        DACreditMax.Fill(DSCreditMax, "DSCreditMaxHere")
        CreditMax = DSCreditMax.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)

        TCNewRowCredit = DSTranCons.Tables(0).NewRow
        With TCNewRowCredit
            .Item(0) = CreditMax + 1
            If txtIfEditingSaved.Text = "" Then
                .Item(1) = txtTranNo.Text   
            Else
                .Item(1) = txtIfEditingSaved.Text    'THIS NUMBER IS INCORRECTLY INSERTED.Check
            End If
            .Item(2) = txtInvNumber.Text
            .Item(3) = dtpSaleInvoice.Value
            .Item(7) = DSMisclExpDetTemp.Tables(0).Rows(I).Item(4)
            .Item(8) = DSMisclExpDetTemp.Tables(0).Rows(I).Item(2)  'Amount is entered here
            .Item(9) = txtComboAccount.Text  '  'This is the opposite account ID which will be used for the ledger display from TranConsolidated. 'Inserts the Debit account selected in the voucher
            .Item(10) = 2   'This is a sub transaction of sales tran
            .Item(12) = frmAddMisclinSale.txtTranSubType.Text
        End With
        DSTranCons.Tables(0).Rows.Add(TCNewRowCredit)
        '  Loop
    Next I

End Sub
```

In the above code,I have to save some items into a table(TranConsolidated).Depending on the number of records in other tables,I count the rows in the tables and then run the loop for that many times.
Note that in the destination table(TranConsolidated)I have to create the primary which is not AutoNumber and I obtain each new key by obtaining the max number of last record in the table and then adding 1 to it.

However,I get a "Insert Into"syntax error.Note that I have repeatedly checked the table for any system keywords and found none.Also,there is another place from which I save to the same table without any problems.
Even here I had earlier been able to save successfully but encountered problems when I set up the code to insert the new primary key at each iteration.

Khalid.

Comment: Please provide the exact error message and the line it occurs on.

Comment: The error message is "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." and occurs at the update command "DATranCons.Update(DSTranCons, "DSTranConsHere")"

Comment: Read up on DataAdapters (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y(v=vs.110).aspx). When the Update method is called, it goes through and processes any Inserts, Updates and Deletes necessary to sync the dataset with the underlying table.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but I don't see any `DATranCons.Update(DSTranCons, "DSTranConsHere")` code in your question.

Comment: @Mark I concur, it's not there.

Comment: The "DATranCons.Update(DSTranCons, "DSTranConsHere")" was mistakenly removed from this post.However it definitely exists in my program's code.

Comment: Jeremy,Does this mean that there is some issue with the generation of the primary key for the two rows which is interfering with the Update to the underlying table?